# Sublime Text 3 treats .sass files as "Ruby Haml"

Tags: sass, haml, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to fix it? This drives me crazy, it's not that important until you press CMD-/ to comment the code and then it adds HAML comments (one slash instead of two) that break SASS.

So I have to change language manually to SASS every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, that's possible. Within the View menu, find the 'Syntax' item, the look for the 'Open all with current extension as...' option. In there, choose Sass.